# Running ASP.NET 5 project on IIS locally

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am trying to get https://github.com/warden-stack/Warden/tree/master/src/Web/Warden.Web working on IIS. It works when I run it through IIS Express in Visual Studio, but when I publish it and set the physical address in the /wwwroot - I get the following error:

[image: error 500.19]

[image: app config advanced]

[image: app config basic]

This is within the published web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpplatformhandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="..\approot\web.cmd" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="..\logs\stdout.log" startupTimeLimit="3600"></httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

What would I need to change to make ASP5 run through IIS, locally? If this is possible of course.

Comment: What does the app pool config look like? i.e. Is it set to use.Net Framework 4 instead of 2?

Comment: @DavidG - I have attached the basic and advanced settings of the app pool config.

Comment: .Net Version needs to be v4

Comment: @DavidG - changed it to v4 and error still occurs.

Comment: Exactly the same error?

Comment: @DavidG Yep. Nothing changed.

Comment: The .Net Framework setting in the application pool needs to be set to **No Managed Code**.  But I see that project is an RC1 project.  RC2 is out and it is completely different in how it works with IIS.  You're wasting your time trying to get an RC1 project to work with IIS.

Comment: May i have your web.config file of your project please.

Comment: @Divyesh - He already posted his web.config.  That's all there is in the web.config for an ASP.NET 5/Core RC1 application.

Comment: @ClintB - what would be the best approach to do so? And what are the guarantees that RC2 will work with IIS.